# How do I attach events to Natural Earth map data created in TileMill?

Tags: javascript, mapbox

I realize there are some conceptual gaps in my knowledge—I'm not 100% clear on how everything fits together in Mapbox. Hopefully someone can set me straight and help me achieve what I'm trying to do.

Our client is a multinational corporation with locations divided into global regions: North America, South America, Europe & Africa, Asia Pacific, etc.

What they want is for the initial map view to be a zoomed-out world map. When each of these individual regions are moused over, the countries belonging to that region will be highlighted, a label will be displayed with the name of the region, and clicking will zoom the viewport to center/display the region.

The problem is that there is no concept of a region in the map, and I'm not sure how to add one programatically.

The underlying country map was created and styled by a designer using TileMill. It uses the Natural Earth country map. When I look at the project in TileMill and inspect the layer "features", it appears that the shapefile has a list of the individual countries with some associated metadata. So far so good.

Ideally, on the client side, I would have a list of countries belonging to each region. When the user mouses over an individual country, I'll figure out what region it belongs to, iterate through the country list and apply an effect (like opacity) to highlight the region.

The problem is, I can't figure out how to get the country metadata in the TileMill file for whatever country is currently being moused over. Is it even possible to attach events and access the features added in TileMill?

FYI: an alternate approach I tried was adding [this](https://github.com/johan/world.geo.json) map data at runtime. I was able to attach events to GeoJSON features, but the granularity of the map is WAY lower than the underlying map, so it doesn't line up correctly at higher zoom levels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The problem is that there is no concept of a region in the map, and I'm not sure how to add one programatically.

Okay, so the fundamental thing to understand here is the difference between interactivity you add in TileMill and interactivity via GeoJSON, in Mapbox.js.

- TileMill supports *raster* interactivity based on [UTFGrid](https://www.mapbox.com/foundations/an-open-platform/#utfgrid), and exports *tiles*. It can handle high levels of detail and thousands of features, but since the *geo data itself is not transferred to your browser*, you can't do hover interactions like highlighting data - you can only open tooltips and popups
- Mapbox.js/Leaflet support *vector* interactivity. They can handle much lower levels of detail and amounts of data. But the *geo data is transferred to your browser*, so you can do hover interactions as well as adding tooltips.

Comment: Thanks. I got the sense that it wasn't possible because the TileMill-related APIs only deal with tiles, but it was helpful to hear it explained clearly. Worked around it by limiting zoom to a level where the differences aren't visible.